# Logon failure: The target account name is incorrect

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Yesterday I was having a computer in the office give me the error
" the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed "

So I went and rejoined the computer to the domain using the Network ID option in system properties.

> This computer is part of a business network
>   company uses a network with domain
>   entered the information 
>   told me that there was already a PC named this would I like to use this one. Yes

Then I was prompted to restart the PC and when it rebooted the trust relationship issue had went sways, but upon logging in I found out that I received a new error when the computer tried to get the desktop/my documents from the redirected folder

\server\redirectedfolders\user\desktop is not accessible. logon failure the target account name is incorrect.

However , when I use this users credentials on another office computer, I do not receive this issue and everything loads up fine

The server is running Windows Server 2012R2

Apologies for my "typooes" I am using a mobile decive currently and didn't think I could actually manage to have typos

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the machine account was not removed when you rejoined.

When this happens to me, I use Active Directory Users and Computers to clear out the machine account and then rejoin.

Comment: Alright, when searching for a solution I found this as a possible cause/suggestion, but when I went to the active directory I didn't see it listed under computers, but there is another tab under MyBusiness that has computers (and also the one in question) would this be done the same way as if it were under the server.local computers tab?

Comment: If you can right-click and delete the machine account. It should be the equivalent.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a try as soon as I get back to the office and accept the answer if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, 
1. Remove the computer from the domain.
2. Delete the Computer Object on Active Directory.
3. Rejoin the computer to the domain.

Also, check this step by step guide about How to solve the "Trusted Issue"
[How to solve the "Trusted Issue"](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/03/18/fix-the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain-failed/)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, I am still receiving the same error, I will check out the link you sent now and see if I can address it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue connecting to a network share like `\server`, giving

> logon failure the target account name is incorrect.

In my case, the reason was that there was a `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` entry pointing to localhost

```
127.0.0.1    server
```

Also, trying to do a remote desktop connection to that PC gives a strange error message like

> Your computer could no connect to console session on the remote computer because you already have a console session in progress